# Why is this error of no assembly found is generated? master.extpython

Tags: python-3.x, u-sql

I am trying to get to Python UDO. A simple code is giving error as assembly not found

It is the first test for getting python working on ADLA

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [ExtPython];

DECLARE @myScript = @"

def usqlml_main(df):
    return df
";

@t  = 
    SELECT * FROM 
            (VALUES
            ("key1",100),
            ("key1",101),
            ("key2",200),
            ("key3",202)
        ) AS 
              D( partitionkey, value );

@m  =
    REDUCE @t ON partitionkey
    PRODUCE partitionkey string, value string
    USING new Extension.Python.Reducer(pyScript:@myScript);


OUTPUT @m
  TO "/output.csv"
  USING Outputters.Csv();
```

This should run the error is Assembly 'master.ExtPython' does not exist.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register your assembly in your local database.
So first create a script to do that.

```
DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS [ExtPython];

CREATE ASSEMBLY [ExtPython] FROM @"Assemblies/ExtPython.dll";
```

Put your dll in the assemblies folder so the script can get it and register it.

The default U-SQL local folder is ..\AppData\Local\USQLDataRoot. So create and folder like AppData\Local\USQLDataRoot\Assemblies.

Or you can just put the code above in your script before the reference.